# Get Coordinates of Moving Pointer in SwiftUI (iPadOS)

Tags: swift, ipad, swiftui, ipados

On the iPad, I'm trying to build a simple app that *continuously* tracks the pointer's coordinates as it moves across the screen (via external mouse/trackpad). Basically something like this [JavaScript example @ 4:13](https://youtu.be/P2i11xnrpNI?t=253) except in a SwiftUI view on the iPad.

MacOS has [NSEvent.mouseLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31931403/5606164), but it doesn't seem like there's an iPadOS counterpart. Every resource I've come across online necessarily associates coordinates with a gesture (rotation, pinch, drag, click, etc.) with no way to respond to *only* cursor movement. This leads me to believe that the solution for pure pointer movement is likely independent of the Gesture protocol.

I was able to get halfway there after modifying code from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58318770/5606164). My code below displays updated mouse coordinates *so long as the pointer is dragging* (i.e., while at least one button is pressed).

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var pt = CGPoint()
    @State private var txt = "init"

    var body: some View {
        let myGesture = DragGesture(
            minimumDistance: 0,
            coordinateSpace: .local
        )
        .onChanged {
            self.pt = $0.location
            self.txt = "x: \(self.pt.x), y: \(self.pt.y)"
        }


        // Spacers needed to make the VStack occupy the whole screen
        return VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(self.txt)
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(width: 1000, height: 1000)
        .border(Color.green)
        .contentShape(Rectangle()) // Make the entire VStack tappabable, otherwise, only the area with text generates a gesture
        .gesture(myGesture) // Add the gesture to the Vstack
    }
}
```

Now, how do I achieve this effect *without* needing to drag? Could there be some way to do this with the help of objective-C if a pure Swift solution isn't possible?

Thanks

Edit:

Comment: How is it supposed to track *touch* if there ins't a finger down?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to get coords following a touch event. I am trying to just constantly read in the coords as the pointer moves around the screen.

Comment: What is moving the pointer around? An Apple Pencil?

Comment: An external pointing device (mouse/trackpad). I'll add that to the post to clarify.

Comment: Have you tried watching the video?

Comment: Yes, I don't believe it covers pure movement. From what I understand, their use cases require an associated gesture (rotation, pinch, tap, drag, etc.).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234676/discussion-between-a-is-for-ambition-and-jeshua-lacock).

Comment: See the tutorial on Pointer Support that I found for you in my answer.

Comment: Does the tutorial not show you exactly what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WWDC video covers this very topic:

[Handle trackpad and mouse input](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10094/)

Add `SupportsIndirectInputEvents` to your `Info.plist`

From the video:

> It is required in order to get the new touch type indirect pointer and
> EventType.transform.
> Existing projects do not have this key set and will need to add it. Starting with iOS 14 and macOS Big Sur SDKs, new UIKit and SwiftUI
> projects will have this value set to "true."

In addition you will use `UIPointerInteraction`. This tutorial shows you step by step including custom cursors:

https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2020/supporting-pointer-interactions/

Comment: This is iOS 14 so it has already been added my project's Info.plist by default. However, taking a look at the features available when set to true (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uiapplicationsupportsindirectinputevents), I don't think this solves the original question of coordinate tracking, right?

Comment: Why the downvotes? I'm pointing the OP directly to information that answers their question.